# Remove lines with CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm using a plugin that has below output:

```
<div class="CUSTOM CODE">
    <ul>
        <li> line 1 </li>
        <li> line 2 </li>
        <li> line 3 </li>
        <li> line 4 </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The problem is I need to keep single line for example line1. I can control CSS classes only. Is is possible to do this job through CSS class?

Comment: Yes. https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/nth-child/

Comment: `.CUSTOM.CODE li:first-child { background-color: red;  }`

Comment: Yes this code worked but I want remove line not only change background color.

Comment: did you use `list-style:none;`?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this kind of code.

```
.CUSTOM ul li:nth-child(2){
   background:black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `:not` and `:first-child`

```css
.CUSTOM li:not(:first-child){display:none;}
```

```html
<div class="CUSTOM CODE">
    <ul>
        <li> line 1 </li>
        <li> line 2 </li>
        <li> line 3 </li>
        <li> line 4 </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This may not work in IE 8 or IE 7 : http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3

Answer (score 0):

At css, example changing line1:

```
ul li:nth-child(1)
{
    /* example */
    color: green;
    border:2px solid black;
    padding:6px;
}
```

Or at html, example changing line4  :

```
<div>
 <ul>
  <li> line 1 </li>
  <li> line 2 </li>
  <li> line 3 </li>
  <li style="color:blue;padding:6px;"> line 4 </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```css
.CUSTOM.CODE li:first-child {display:none}
```

```html
<div class="CUSTOM CODE">
    <ul>
        <li> line 1 </li>
        <li> line 2 </li>
        <li> line 3 </li>
        <li> line 4 </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```